# Sympy: respect i^^2 = -1 in expansions

Tags: sympy

When executing the following

```
from sympy import *

R, L, C, w = symbols("R L C w", real = True)
j = symbols("j", real = False)

H = (1 + j * w * C * R) * (j * w * L + R)
H = H.expand()

print(H)
print(latex(H))
```

the result is as stated below.

```
C*L*R*j**2*w**2 + C*R**2*j*w + L*j*w + R
C L R j^{2} w^{2} + C R^{2} j w + L j w + R
```

I want to set j^2 = -1 and j^3 = -j and so on, if necessary.
How to do that in this calculation?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sympy recognizes the imaginary constant as `sympy.I`.

```
>>> import sympy
>>> sympy.I**2
-1
```